# jQuery Sorting table columns according to content in 'sub-div' inside 'td'

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I have a table in which the first row has content within two 'divs' inside each 'td'. The remaining two rows have the content in the 'td' itself.

The table needs to be sorted (in ascending order) by columns as per the parameter selected in the 'sort' dropdown. (The content in the 'divs' and respective dropdown text have been color-coded for understanding as in image below).

[image]

The jquery I'm using to sort the 2nd & 3rd rows with the content in the td itself is as follows, which is working fine:

```
var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());
                RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
                    a = $(a).text();
                    b = $(b).text();
                    return (a === 'NA')-(b === 'NA') || -(a>b)||+(a<b);
                }).each(function(new_Index) {
                    var original_Index = $(this).index();

                    Rows.each(function() {
                    var td = $(this).find('td, th');
                    if (original_Index !== new_Index)
                    td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
                    });
                });
```

However, when I use this for the first row to target the 'divs' within each 'td', it is sorting it incorrectly:

```
var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr.Statistics");
**var DivtoSort = $(".CompTable tr.Statistics td:not(:first) div." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());**

            DivtoSort.sort(function(a, b) {
            a = $(a).text();
            b = $(b).text();            
            return (a === 'NA')-(b === 'NA') || -(a>b)||+(a<b);
            }).each(function(new_Index) {
                var original_Index = $(this).index();

                Rows.each(function() {
                var td = $(this).find('td, th');
                if (original_Index !== new_Index)
                td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
                });
            });
            }
```

Below is the entire working code for reference:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#SortBy").on('change', function() {

    var Rows = $('.CompTable tr');
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr("name") == "Statistics") {

      var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr.Statistics");
      var DivtoSort = $(".CompTable tr.Statistics td:not(:first) div." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());

      DivtoSort.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = $(a).text();
        b = $(b).text();
        return (a === 'NA') - (b === 'NA') || -(a > b) || +(a < b);
      }).each(function(new_Index) {
        var original_Index = $(this).index();

        Rows.each(function() {
          var td = $(this).find('td, th');
          if (original_Index !== new_Index)
            td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
        });
      });
    } else {
      var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());
      RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
        a = $(a).text();
        b = $(b).text();
        return (a === 'NA') - (b === 'NA') || -(a > b) || +(a < b);
      }).each(function(new_Index) {
        var original_Index = $(this).index();

        Rows.each(function() {
          var td = $(this).find('td, th');
          if (original_Index !== new_Index)
            td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.CompTable td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SortByDiv">
  Sort by:
  <select id="SortBy">
    <option></option>
    <option name=Statistics style="color: blue">Statistics1</option>
    <option name=Statistics style="color: red">Statistics2</option>
    <option name=Parameter1>Parameter1</option>
    <option name=Parameter2>Parameter2</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <div class="divResult">
    <table class="CompTable">
      <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Samsung</th>
        <th>Apple</th>
        <th>Motorola</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="Statistics">
          <td>Statistics</td>
          <td>
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
              <div class="Statistics1" style="display:flex; color:blue; width: 100%;">3200</div>
              <div class="Statistics2" style="display:flex; color:red; width: 100%;">0</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
              <div class="Statistics1" style="display:flex; color:blue; width: 100%;">1500</div>
              <div class="Statistics2" style="display:flex; color:red; width: 100%;">NA</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
              <div class="Statistics1" style="display:flex; color:blue; width: 100%;">4100</div>
              <div class="Statistics2" style="display:flex; color:red; width: 100%;">1500</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Parameter1">
          <td>Parameter1</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>7000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Parameter2">
          <td>Parameter2</td>
          <td>5000</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>7000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find()` to filter table inner `div`

```
  a = $(a).find(datasub)
  b = $(b).find(datasub)
```

based on the `data-sub`

```
<option name=Statistics data-sub="Statistics1" style="color: blue">Statistics1</option>
<option name=Statistics data-sub="Statistics2" style="color: red">Statistics2</option>
```

```js
$("#SortBy").on('change', function() {
  var datasub = $(this).find("option:selected").data('sub')
  datasub = datasub ? '.' + datasub : undefined;

  var Rows = $('.CompTable tr');
  var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").attr('name'));
  RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (datasub) {
      a = $(a).find(datasub)
      b = $(b).find(datasub)
    }
    a = $(a).text();
    b = $(b).text();
    return (a === 'NA') - (b === 'NA') || -(a > b) || +(a < b);
  }).each(function(new_Index) {
    var original_Index = $(this).index();

    Rows.each(function() {
      var td = $(this).find('td, th');
      if (original_Index !== new_Index)
        td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.CompTable td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SortByDiv">
  Sort by:
  <select id="SortBy">
    <option></option>
    <option name=Statistics data-sub="Statistics1" style="color: blue">Statistics1</option>
    <option name=Statistics data-sub="Statistics2" style="color: red">Statistics2</option>
    <option name=Parameter1>Parameter1</option>
    <option name=Parameter2>Parameter2</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <div class="divResult">
    <table class="CompTable">
      <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Samsung</th>
        <th>Apple</th>
        <th>Motorola</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="Statistics">
          <td>Statistics</td>
          <td>
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
              <div class="Statistics1" style="display:flex; color:blue; width: 100%;">3200</div>
              <div class="Statistics2" style="display:flex; color:red; width: 100%;">0</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
              <div class="Statistics1" style="display:flex; color:blue; width: 100%;">1500</div>
              <div class="Statistics2" style="display:flex; color:red; width: 100%;">NA</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%;">
              <div class="Statistics1" style="display:flex; color:blue; width: 100%;">4100</div>
              <div class="Statistics2" style="display:flex; color:red; width: 100%;">1500</div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Parameter1">
          <td>Parameter1</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>7000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Parameter2">
          <td>Parameter2</td>
          <td>5000</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>7000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Learnt something new!! :)

Comment: One question, what does this `datasub = datasub ? '.' + datasub : undefined;` do? How do u read this? Again, thanks a lot, amazing reply!! :)

Comment: @MithunUchil Its [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)